# Scraping a value of a website using VBA where the classname is duplicated

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Ok This question has a 2 parts to it.

1. I need to scrape the value R1200 from the website into Excel using VBA. I have tried various methods and I cant seem to get it right. @QHarr offered a solution that worked but I think the format of the website has changed.
2. The code runs when I step through it using keyboard button F8 but it falls over when I run it normally.

Sections:

1. This is the HTML where the value R1200 is stored, The "clearfix extras" element is not unique, The one I want is the 4th one shown below:

```html
<ul class="clearfix extras">
    <li>
        Document admin fee<span>R 99.00</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        Vehicle Rental <span>R 2870.00</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <!--This is part of the temporary solution to show the oneway surcharge-->
        One Way Drop Off Surcharge<span>R 1200.00</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The below are all the things I have tried, Is it possible to use query selector to identify the 4th instance of "clearfix extras"?:

```
`Cells(r, 3).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3").getElementsByClassName("optional-extras").querySelector(".clearfix.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
Cells(r, 3).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3").getElementsByClassName("itinerary wide").getElementsByClassName("itinerary-container clearfix").querySelector(".optional.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
Cells(r, 4).Value = appIE.document.querySelector(".clearfix.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
Cells(r, 5).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3").getElementsByClassName("itinerary wide").getElementsByClassName("itinerary-container clearfix").querySelector(".clearfix.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
Cells(r, 6).Value = appIE.document.querySelector(".thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3.itinerary.wide.itinerary-container.clearfix.itinerary-container.clearfix li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
Cells(r, 7).Value = appIE.document.querySelector(".clearfix.extras:nth-of-type(3) li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
Cells(r, 3).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3").getElementsByClassName("itinerary wide").getElementsByClassName("itinerary-container clearfix").querySelector(".optional.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
Set OWF = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3")
Cells(r, 3).Value = OWF.querySelector("li:nth-of-type(2) span").innerText
Cells(r, 5).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3").getElementsByClassName("itinerary wide").getElementsByClassName("itinerary-container clearfix").querySelector(".clearfix.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
Cells(r, 6).Value = appIE.document.querySelector(".thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3.itinerary.wide.itinerary-container.clearfix.itinerary-container.clearfix li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
Cells(r, 7).Value = appIE.document.querySelector(".clearfix.extras:nth-of-type(3) li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText`
```

2. I have been using the below code (my full code) but I find that my code falls over all the time at various points. Is there a better way to do this? Unfortunately my code has to navigate through many pages(and fill in details) just to get to the R1200 value that I require. Perhaps my app.wait parts are used incorrectly? I know that the code is incomplete, I need to figure out how to get it to loop for all cars, not just the "Kia Picanto". Im just trying to  figure out how to get parts 1 and 2 of my question sorted for now. Thanks

Code:

```
Private Sub test1()
    Dim appIE As Object
    Dim e As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim O
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    Dim c As String
    Dim d As String
    Dim PickUp As Object
    Dim iL As IHTMLElement
    Dim f As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim post As Object
    Dim Ret As Object
    Dim entry As Object
    Dim l As Object

    r = 2

    Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Test2")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With appIE
        .navigate "https://www.europcar.co.za"
        .Visible = True


        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
        Do While appIE.Busy
            DoEvents
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
        Loop
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

        For i = 2 To 2
            With ws
                a = .Cells(i, 8)
                d = .Cells(i, 9)
                b = .Cells(i, 10)
                c = .Cells(i, 11)
            End With

            Do While appIE.Busy And e Is Nothing
                DoEvents
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
            Loop
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

            Set e = appIE.document.getElementById("PickupBranch_BranchID_id")
            For Each O In e.Options
                If O.Value = a Then
                    O.Selected = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            Do While appIE.Busy And e Is Nothing
                DoEvents
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
            Loop
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

            Set e = appIE.document.getElementById("ReturnBranch_BranchID_id")
            For Each O In e.Options
                If O.Value = d Then
                    O.Selected = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            Do While appIE.Busy And f Is Nothing
                DoEvents
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
            Loop

            Set f = appIE.document.getElementById("timepicker-pickup").getElementsByTagName("li")
            For Each iL In f
                If iL.innerText = "09" Then
                    iL.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next iL

            Do While appIE.Busy And post Is Nothing
                DoEvents
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
            Loop

            Set post = appIE.document.getElementsByName("PickupDate")
            For Each post In appIE.document.getElementsByName("PickupDate")
                post.Value = b
            Next post

            Do While appIE.Busy And Ret Is Nothing
                DoEvents
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
            Loop

            Set Ret = appIE.document.getElementsByName("ReturnDate")
            For Each Ret In appIE.document.getElementsByName("ReturnDate")
                Ret.Value = c
            Next Ret

            Do While appIE.Busy And l Is Nothing
                DoEvents
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
            Loop
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

            For Each l In appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn search-btn")
                If l.className = "btn search-btn" Then
                    l.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
            On Error Resume Next
            Do While appIE.Busy
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
                DoEvents
            Loop

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

            For Each k In appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("filtered-vehicles")(0).getElementsByClassName("vehicle box-shadow-dark-2").getElementsByClassName("KIA PICANTO")

                For Each l In appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("select-btn btn grey")
                    If l.className = "select-btn btn grey" Then
                        l.Click

                        Exit For
                    End If
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
                    Exit For
                Next

            Next

            For Each q In appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn search-btn")
                If q.className = "btn search-btn" Then
                    q.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next


            For Each Z In appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn search-btn")
                If Z.className = "btn search-btn" Then
                    Z.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

            Do While appIE.Busy
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
                DoEvents
            Loop
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

            .document.getElementById("TitleID").Value = "8"

            appIE.document.all.item("step4-initials").Value = "U"
            appIE.document.all.item("step4-first-name").Value = "Underhill"
            appIE.document.all.item("step4-surname").Value = "Tsonga"
            appIE.document.all.item("step4-surname").Value = "Tsonga"
            appIE.document.all.item("step4-email").Value = "Car@Check.com"
            appIE.document.all.item("step4-contact-num").Value = "0915598452"
            appIE.document.all.item("step4-id-number").Value = "0112022374"

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            On Error Resume Next
            Do While appIE.Busy
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
                DoEvents
            Loop

            appIE.document.getElementById("terms_and_conditions").Click

            For Each Z In appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn search-btn")
                If Z.className = "btn search-btn" Then
                    Z.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next Z

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            Do While appIE.Busy
                DoEvents
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
            Loop

            Cells(r, 1).Value = Mid(appIE.document.querySelector(".vehicle-information h5:nth-of-type(1) ").innerText, 7, 1)
            Cells(r, 2).Value = Mid(appIE.document.querySelector(".vehicle-information h5:nth-of-type(1) ").innerText, 8, 16)
            Cells(r, 3).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3").getElementsByClassName("optional-extras").querySelector(".clearfix.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
            Cells(r, 3).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3").getElementsByClassName("itinerary wide").getElementsByClassName("itinerary-container clearfix").querySelector(".optional.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
            Cells(r, 4).Value = appIE.document.querySelector(".clearfix.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
            Cells(r, 5).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3").getElementsByClassName("itinerary wide").getElementsByClassName("itinerary-container clearfix").querySelector(".clearfix.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
            Cells(r, 6).Value = appIE.document.querySelector(".thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3.itinerary.wide.itinerary-container.clearfix.itinerary-container.clearfix li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
            Cells(r, 7).Value = appIE.document.querySelector(".clearfix.extras:nth-of-type(3) li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
            Cells(r, 3).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3").getElementsByClassName("itinerary wide").getElementsByClassName("itinerary-container clearfix").querySelector(".optional.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
            Set OWF = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3")
            Cells(r, 3).Value = OWF.querySelector("li:nth-of-type(2) span").innerText
            Cells(r, 5).Value = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3").getElementsByClassName("itinerary wide").getElementsByClassName("itinerary-container clearfix").querySelector(".clearfix.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
            Cells(r, 6).Value = appIE.document.querySelector(".thank-you-message box-shadow-dark-3.itinerary.wide.itinerary-container.clearfix.itinerary-container.clearfix li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText
            Cells(r, 7).Value = appIE.document.querySelector(".clearfix.extras:nth-of-type(3) li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText

            .navigate "https://www.europcar.co.za"
            .Visible = True

            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

            Do While appIE.Busy
                DoEvents
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
            Loop

            r = r + 1

        Next i

    End With
    appIE.Quit
    Set appIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: you should indicate which line it fails on as it is likely a timing issue.

Comment: Please also provide the input values necessary to generate the output value of R 1200.00

Comment: a= 10 , d = 76 , b = 2019/05/15, c = 2019/05/25. Regarding the timing issue, I find that it mostly fails on -   For Each k In appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("filtered-vehicles")(0).getElementsByClassName("vehicle box-shadow-dark-2").getElementsByClassName("KIA PICANTO")
It does break at various points though, usually during the page changes.

Comment: joburg return king shaka? Also, might be worth splitting your question into separate posts and deal with one problem per post.

Comment: Yes that's correct @QHarr, Joburg to King Shaka. I will split questions in the future. makes sense to keep questions separate.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult without test values to enter into the website to generate the values you wish to scrape. Please provide those.

The selector for that value you mention is:

```
.clearfix.extras li:nth-of-type(3) span
```

Though this will select the first element with class name `clearfix extras` so you may need a different index.

Example for the 4th matching class name:

```
.clearfix.extras:nth-of-type(4) li:nth-of-type(3) span
```

Comment: I tried `Cells(r, 4).Value = appIE.document.querySelector(".clearfix.extras:nth-of-type(4) li:nth-of-type(3) span").innerText' but it returned nothing.

Comment: joburg return king shaka ? out15 may back 25th may, what times?

Comment: what times out and return?

Comment: Any times. In my code I set value '09' for the timer. It doesn't matter as long as theres a few days between.

Comment: And can you give a short description of what your code is supposed to achieve? Concise as possible.

Comment: I wish to return Car name, Cargroup (eg :'T' for a  kia picanto) and One Way drop off surcharge for all combinations of stations and available car groups. The one way fee may or may not be visable for different combinations of stations and cars.The car groups will differ based on what is available. I wish to paste these values in Excel. hope that makes sense @QHarr

Comment: So a potential problem is that certain combinations will not return a value due to no availability? How is that indicated?

Comment: Well, in the html the value simply will not appear. So certain cars wont be visable and certain routes wont necessarily have a one way fee so it wont be visable. My idea for the car issue was to fix the loop where I hard coded the 'kia picanto' but the One way fee is tricky as it wont always be visable.