# Web scraping by link text

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have some experience and knowledge how to **scrape** by tagName or ClassName. However in this particular case className is not unique also link is changing all the time after accessing the page so it is not possible to get a direct link. The only unique combination is class and link text. What would be the code to access for example `Budget and Forecast updating` with `a_1_610` and `Budget and Forecast updating` with `a_1_611`?

My code (edited according to QHarr answer):

```
Sub GoToLiinosBot()

'This will load a webpage in IE
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim HWNDSrc As Long
Dim elements As Object

Set ie = Nothing
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

ie.Visible = True

ie.Navigate "http://link.com"

With ie

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
End With

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
    
    ie.Document.querySelector(".data .a_1_611").innerText

'Unload IE
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is source code:

[image]

Comment: There are a number of ways that you could achieve this, you could get a collection of the nodes that contain the class that you desire then loop through those assessing the inner.text or inner.html to look for your desired node (using .getElementsByClassName() [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840179/6387479)) - Another method which arguably would be the most efficient would be to use `.querySelector()` to locate the node directly like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56005033/6387479) / [w3schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

Comment: [Another resource for the selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) (not edited as character limit reached) in particular: `[attribute*=value] a[href*="w3schools"] Selects every <a> element whose href attribute value contains the substring "w3schools"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are class names not ids. A loop is perhaps required, with test of innerText value of node, if ordering changes but otherwise you want the first match for the example shown in image

```
.data .a_1_611
```

Which is

```
ie.document.querySelector(".data .a_1_611").click
```

`nth-of-type` is useful for fixed position selection but more expensive than class selectors.

Comment: this gives an error 5002 `Application-defined or object-defined error`. Also please see edited question with the rest of the source code, as it continuous. There are 5 variants with class `.a_1_611` inside `.data`

Comment: but is the first the required one?  Put .data .a_1_611 in the browser to check in the search box. The error doesn't seem right . Is it occurring on that line?

Comment: I have added to my question search result for `.data .a_1_611`. Yes, first one should be picked but it would be interesting to know how to pick also second one for example. Error points to `ie.document.querySelector(".data .a_1_611").innerText`. I have edited my code in question is it right or should there be `.Click` as it is link?

Comment: If you want to click then ie.document.querySelector(".data .a_1_611").Click

Comment: The second one: .data .a_1_611 .data .a_1_611 is one way

Comment: .data .a_1_611:nth-of-type(2) though it might complain at that syntax